# Can I cancel out factorials in proofs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I encountered the following question in a discrete math course:

> Prove that
>   $ \binom{2n}{k-1} < \binom{2n}{k} $
>   for $k = 1, 2, \ldots , n$.
>
> Hint: This should be a very cleanly written proof.

I'm working through this proof and I'm at a step where I have similar numerators but with a factorial.

My question is: Can I "cancel out" factorials?

Comment: Well, factorials are simply product of integers, and if you have the same set of integers in numerator and denominator, you can cancel them, so...

Comment: Do you need a proof for that combinatorial identity? If so, then I can write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: After you cancel out factorials, you will find out that
$$
\frac{\binom{2n}{k}}{\binom{2n}{k-1}} = \frac{2n-k+1}{k} > 1.
$$

Comment: Damn! I was gonna post this one. :(

Comment: As my good deed for today, I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 4):

You can cancel, but you have to be careful how you do it.  For example:
$\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}$ can be reduced to $\frac{1}{k+1}$ by cancelling the factorial portion on top, but you CANNOT cancel like: $\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{k}{k+1}$ effectively cancelling the "!" symbol.

Think about what the factorial means and it will be clear what you can do.

$$\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)...(3)(2)(1)}{(k+1)(k)(k-1)(k-2)...(3)(2)(1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}.$$

Other factorials are similar.  Handy things to keep in mind are facts like $(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$, etc.

Comment: Or, from the definition of factorial, $(k+1)! = k!(k+1)$, which makes the cancellation "obvious".